# Laravel reusable functions

Tags: php, laravel, repository-pattern

I am using **Repository design pattern** and I have a function `generateBarcode()` this function just do some logic and insert data in database.

I am calling this function in more one function and more that one repository to generate a new Barcode.

> Question is:

What is the best way to make this function reusable?

1. **Helpers**

But I don't think this is a good idea since it am dealing with database.

2. **Events**

Firing event and storing the result.
`$barcode = event(new NewBarcodeRequired())`

*That what I am doing right now and data is returned as an array*

Also I don't think that is a good idea because I have read that events shouldn't return data.

3. **Repository**

Create a new repository for this function but I think it is a very bad idea because I won't create a class for every reusable function that I have.

Comment: what about traits ?

Comment: @AnarBayramov So I will have to create a class for this single function?

Comment: why cant you have a class for single function ?

Comment: A trait seems like a good option if the code in each repository is similar. That way you can define the function once and `use` it in all the repositories where you need to generate barcodes. It doesn't matter if there is only one function in the trait.

Comment: @newUserName02 why shouldn't i use event in this case? I could simple create a new product and fire and event to generate the code then store that event result in a variable and assign it to the created product

Comment: @AnarBayramov I have searched for what you say and true Traits are very useful in this case.. you can post it as a result so it can help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Traits** could be a good option for this case. Which will give you flexibility to use in any of your class without requirement of class extension.

> Traits are a mechanism for code reuse in single inheritance languages such as PHP. A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single inheritance by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in several independent classes living in different class hierarchies. The semantics of the combination of Traits and classes is defined in a way which reduces complexity, and avoids the typical problems associated with multiple inheritance and Mixins.
>
> A Trait is similar to a class, but only intended to group
>   functionality in a fine-grained and consistent way. It is not possible
>   to instantiate a Trait on its own. It is an addition to traditional
>   inheritance and enables horizontal composition of behavior; that is,
>   the application of class members without requiring inheritance.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php